# How to set G-type AFM and U parameters in VASP when optimizing structure?

Tags: vasp, anti-ferromagnetic, reproducing-data-from-papers

I am trying to reproduce results from research. In computation details part, it mentioned some setting about G-type AFM and Hubbard parameter:
1.

> A Hubbard parameter (U) of 5 eV was used to treat the on-site Coulomb interaction for the Fe 3d states.

2. 

> The geometry optimization was carried out considering the different magnetic configurations (FM, C-AFM, G-AFM) in BFO, and both phases were concluded to be stable in G-type AFM. Further, a larger k-grid mesh was considered for the calculations of the bands under the G-type AFM ordering of the Fe atoms taking into account the spin–orbit coupling (SOC).

Therefore, I'm considering adding Hubbard and AFM parameters in the INCAR file when doing structure optimization. This is my current INCAR. I would like to ask everyone if there are any problems with it, and where it needs to be modified? I have also attached my POSCAR file. I really hope someone can help me. Let me thank everyone in advance.

```bash
Startparameters for VASP 
# Gloabal paramters
ISTART = 0              # Read existing wavefunction =1
ICHARG = 2             # Default=2 if ISTART=0. Non-self-consistent: GGA/LDA band structures, =11
LWAVE =.FALSE.         # Write WAVECAR or not
LORBIT = 11           # band structure and AFM flag

# Parallelisation
LPLANE = .FALSE.       # Real space distribution; supercells 
NCORE = 1              # Max is no. nodes; don't set for hybrids##
KPAR = 10               # Divides k-grid into separate groups

# Electronic relaxation
PREC = Normal          # Precision level, Normal or High
LREAL = .FALSE.           # Auto for molecule containing for than 20 ionics
ENCUT = 500            # Cut-off energy for plane wave basis set, in eV, default=max ENMAX in POTCAR,for bulk structure relaxation, ENCUT=1.3 * default
NELM = 60              # Max SCF steps
NELMIN = 5             # MIN SCF steps
EDIFF = 1E-06          # SCF energy convergence, this number is quite precise
ISPIN = 2              # AFM=2
#IVDW = 11              # DFT-D3 method of Grimme with zero-damping function
#ISYM = 2
#ALGO = Fast 
 
# Ionic relaxation
EDIFFG =  0.001        # Ionic convergence; eV/AA^3
NSW = 0              # MAX Inonic relaxation steps
ISIF = 7               # For single point enegy
IBRION = 2             # = -1 for NSW = -1 or 0
# POTIM = 0.015         #  Step width in ionic relaxations.
# ADDGRID = .TRUE.   # Increase grid; helps GGA convergence
ISMEAR = 0             # Gaussian smearing; metals:1
SIGMA = 0.05           # Smearing value in eV; metals:0.2

# Nonconlinear AFM
# MAGMOM = x y z
LNONCOLLINEAR = .TRUE.
```

```bash
Fe1 Bi1 O3
1.0
        3.7514150143         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         3.7514150143         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000         4.8798279762
   Fe   Bi    O
    1    1    3
Direct
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.523835003
     0.500000000         0.500000000         0.951292992
     0.000000000         0.500000000         0.669587493
     0.500000000         0.000000000         0.669587493
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.143695503
```